# C++ Cannot return all Variables that have been added to a Vector List

Tags: c++, arrays, file, vector

In the program im currently writing, im up to a stage that requires the use of data that has been read through a file. Some of this data contains number elements, so the proper conversions have been done in order to store them in a vector of type string. Up to this point works.

I have a function called robotComplexity, which calculates a value based on other values found in the file, which have already been added to a vector List(all code shall be posted below). The text file contains the following data.

```
A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.
```

As seen in the code below, this file has been split by a dilimiter at the colon and fullstop to first seperate the variables, then the records. The variables have been stored in their respective holders as shown in the code. The function called robotComplexity contains a for loop

```
for(std::size_t i=0; i< partsVector.size(); ++i) { 
 if(partsVector[i] == userChoice) {
   cout << userChoice << stoi(stringMaximum) << endl;
   }
```

The issues with my Code stem from this for loop. The program is able to loop through the file and recongise the first variable, partCode(converted to newChar) of respective values A,B,C,D,E. So for example when a user enters A it returns A, enters B returns B etc. Now my issues come from trying to print out other variables stored in the vector. In the cout << userChoice...etc line, it successfully returns the Letter(example A) but does not return the correct Value for stringMaximum converted to an int. The returned value is 0 where it should be whatever it equals for a partCode A(in this case)

Im asking if anyone could create/fix my for loop such that when cout << "Variable" is called, it can successfuly print to the console the value of that variable according to the partCode

For Example, if the user enters A as the partcode the output should be

code

```
cout << userChoice << partName << stringMaximum  << stringMinimum << stringComplexity << endl;
```

output

```
A 
Head 
1 
2 
15
```

file containing functions

```
struct Part {
char partCode;
std::string partName;
int maximum;
int minimum;
int complexity;
} myPart;

std::vector<string> partsVector;
std::ifstream partsList("Parts.txt");

std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

std::string newChar;
std::stringstream convertChar;

std::string stringMaximum = std::to_string(myPart.maximum);
std::string stringMinimum = std::to_string(myPart.minimum);
std::string stringComplexity = std::to_string(myPart.complexity);

void readFile() //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
 std::string line;

while (std::getline(partsList, line)) {
    line.pop_back();//removing '.' at end of line
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream ss(line);

    convertChar << myPart.partCode;
    convertChar >> newChar;

    // then read each element by delimiter
    int counter = 0;//number of elements you read
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ':')) {//spilt into different records
      switch (counter) {//put into appropriate value-field according to element-count

      case 0:
        newChar = token; //convert partCode from a char to a string 
        break;
      case 1:
        myPart.partName = token;
        break;
      case 2: 
      myPart.maximum =stoi(token);
        break;
      case 3: 
      myPart.minimum = stoi(token);
        break;
        case 4:
         myPart.complexity = stoi(token);
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
      counter++;//increasing counter
    }

partsVector.push_back(newChar);
partsVector.push_back(myPart.partName);
partsVector.push_back(stringMaximum);
partsVector.push_back(stringMinimum);
partsVector.push_back(stringComplexity);

   } 
}

double robotComplexity() { 

double complexity;
string userChoice;

cout << "Enter a part code A ,B ,C ,D or E" << endl;
cin >> userChoice;

for(std::size_t i=0; i< partsVector.size(); ++i) { 
 if(partsVector[i] == userChoice) {
   cout << userChoice << stoi(stringMaximum) << endl;
   }
} 
}
```

Thankyou for any help offered. If any furuther explaination is required please feel free to ask. PS I know global variables aren't the best to use, but once my functions operate correctly I will clean the code up with local variables.

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would let others help you. This snippet is too long to help.

Comment: @LouisGo the code provided is the least amount needed for the program to work and for people to understand the problem .

Comment: Your main calls 4 functions. Is your problem existing in all of 4 functions? If answer is no, then your question is NOT minimal. Even if answer is yes, just show one function. We don't need to understand your throughful use case, just a specific usecase in snippet of code.

Comment: @LouisGo Ill remove main and provide if anyone asks

Comment: From what i can glean from your code, i'm guessing the variables you use to output values are not the same into which you read the values from the file (e.g. in the last code "snippet", you set `stringMaximum` from `myPart.maximum` before you read any vlaue into `myPart`). This could explain it, since some systems default-initalize `int`s with 0 (not something you want to rely on, though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here, but your main problem is that

```
std::string stringMaximum = std::to_string(myPart.maximum);
std::string stringMinimum = std::to_string(myPart.minimum);
std::string stringComplexity = std::to_string(myPart.complexity);
```

are global variables, and **not** functions. They will be evaluated only once at the beginning of your program. So your `readFile` is already broken in the code that you gave us. The first thing I would do is remove the global state (i.e. remove all global variables) and fix the code that doesn't compile anymore.

You do

```
partsVector.push_back(stringMaximum);
partsVector.push_back(stringMinimum);
```

in `readFile` without ever setting those two variables so you always push the same value in your vector.

Next question is, why do you use a vector of string and not a vector of Part? You already parse the file to `Part` objects, so just use them. Furthermore, you want to access those parts via a user input that queries for `Part.partCode`, so we can use a lookup table with `partCode` as a key (`std::unordered_map<char, Part>` in this case).

All in all this would look like the following (the inner while loop in `readFile` was a nightmare too, so I removed that aswell):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Part
{
    char partCode = 0;
    std::string partName;
    int maximum = 0;
    int minimum = 0;
    int complexity = 0;
};

std::stringstream partsList(
    R"(A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.)");

std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

std::unordered_map<char, Part> readFile() //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
    std::unordered_map<char, Part> parts;
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(partsList, line))
    {
        line.pop_back(); //removing '.' at end of line
        std::string token;
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        Part part;

        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.partCode = token[0];
        std::getline(ss, part.partName, ':');
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.maximum = std::stoi(token);
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.minimum = std::stoi(token);
        std::getline(ss, token, ':');
        part.complexity = std::stoi(token);

        parts.emplace(part.partCode, std::move(part));
    }

    return parts;
}

double robotComplexity(std::unordered_map<char, Part> const& parts)
{
    double complexity = 10;
    char partCode;

    std::cout << "Enter a part code A ,B ,C ,D or E" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> partCode;

    auto const& part = parts.at(partCode);
    std::cout << part.maximum;

    if (complexity > 100)
    {
        complexity = 100;
    }

    std::cout << "\nThe Robot Complexity is: " << complexity << std::endl;
    return complexity;
}

void writeFile() //writes to a file output.txt the end calculations.
{
}

int main()
{
    auto parts = readFile();
    writeFile();
    robotComplexity(parts);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the stringStream that contains the contents of the text file needed?

Comment: @DavidLing no you can replace that with your filestream like you had it before. In fact any stream will do.

Comment: I hate to be a pain but is it possible to do the above using vectors instead of maps? I just found out i cant use maps

Comment: @DavidLing of course. Just replace the `parts.emplace` with `parts.push_back(std::move(part))` and `parts.at(partCode);` with `*std::find_if(parts.begin(), parts.end(), [&](auto&& p) { return p.partCode == partCode; });`. It's a bit more verbose but it behaves (almost) the same.

Comment: could you possible put that in an example? its a bit hard to follow

Comment: I would also need to change double robotComplexity(std::unordered_map<char, Part> const& parts) to take in a vector not a map, same for readFile

Comment: You should try to figure that out yourself as a learning practice. It seems like you're not very experienced with programming in general (no offense). Anyway, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/wzkjv7) is an example with vectors instead of maps.

Comment: I do have experience, its just seeing what you wrote as just lines and not in proper format didnt make sense to me.